# Where can I find documentation for _get_comp_words_by_ref function used often in autocompletion scripts?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I am trying to write tests for a bash completion script a user of a tool I am developing wrote (so that I can keep it up to date with the tool itself) and I am wondering what the _get_comp_words_by_ref exactly does.

Sample:

```
local cur prev
if type _get_comp_words_by_ref &>/dev/null ; then
    _get_comp_words_by_ref cur prev
else
    cur=$2 prev=$3
fi
```

Comment: See: `type _get_comp_words_by_ref`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's part of the `bash-completions` package, which might be installed in the directory `/usr/share/bash-completion` (although the precise path depends on the distro).

You may find the documentation [in the top-level file `bash-completion`](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/bash_completion#L532), which contains a number of utility functions.